# Displaying information from a SQL DB into an ERB webpage

Tags: ruby, database, sqlite, sinatra, sequel

I am creating a program with a search bar that searches my SQL DB within my project.

**Index.erb:** I have the code for the search bar in my `index.erb` file.

```
<form method="get" action="/submit">
    <input placeholder="Search" type="text" name="userInput"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

**App.rb:** In my`app.rb` file I use `params[:userInput]` to get the information that the user types into the search bar. Then I pass it through the `.where()` method to search my database for items with the same name. (Note: I'm using sinatra to create my routes).

```
get '/' do
    erb :index
end

get '/submit' do
    @item = Item.where(:name => params[:userInput]) #I created a table called `items` under my migration and a class called `Item` in my models folder
    # puts @item.inspect

    erb :index
end
```

**Index.erb:** Then back in my erb file, I created a `div` where I would like to display the information (with the same name as the word that the user typed in originally) that is gathered from the DB. So I did:

```
<div>
    <%= @item %>
</div>
```

But this only displays a hashtag on my webpage (#). So then I went to my `app.rb` file and did `@item.inspect` under the `/submit` root. I got back:

```
#<Sequel::SQLite::Dataset: "SELECT * FROM 'items' WHERE ('name' = 'apple')">
```

How can I display the actual information from my database that is associated with 'apple' onto my webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I researched, I found that there are many solutions to this problem. I'm going to use a basic and simplistic way.

Within the `Index.erb File`, the code that is written above (`<div> <%= @item %> </div>`) is close to what the desired outcome is. Instead of just writing `@item`, you would write:

```
<div>
    <% @item.each do |x| %> <!-- Or whatever variable you would like to pass -->
        <%= x[:the_id_of_your_hash] %> <!-- You can do this however many times you would like -->
    <% end %>
</div>
```